# what does having two goals in same plugin mean in maven?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

Here is an example of `pom.xml`

```
                   <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.18.1</version>
                            <configuration>
                                ......
                            </configuration>
                            <executions>
                                <execution>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                        <goal>verify</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                                </execution>
                            </executions>
                        </plugin>
                     </plugins>
```

1. what does having two goals here mean?
2. Does verify goal (bound to verify phase) will be executed in `integration-test` phase?
3. Does both `integration-test` and `verify` goal execute during integration-test and in what order?
4. when I run `mvn clean verify`, does `verify` goal executed twice? one during `integration-test` and one during `verify`?

**EDIT**

Given the answer below and the linked documentation, does it mean the plugin is invoked twice when I run `mvn verify` - one in `integration-test` phase and in `verify` phase.

Comment: Have you tried running this script yourself from the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First your given configuration does not make sense, cause the documentation [says different](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/usage.html):

```xml
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

The subtle difference is giving the `phase` or not. In your case you have given `phase` which means binding both goals `integration-test` and `verify` to the same [life cycle phase](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html). If you omit the `phase` as in my example (copied from the documentation) it means the two goals will be bound to the life cycle phases the plugin developer have thought it would be useful. This means binding the `integration-test` goal to the `integration-test` life cycle phase and the `verify` goal to the `verify` life cycle phase.

You can see the phase to which a goal is bound within the documentation like [here](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html) (excerpt from the doc):

- Requires a Maven project to be executed.
- Requires dependency resolution of artifacts in scope: test.
- The goal is thread-safe and supports parallel builds.
  Binds by default to the lifecycle phase: integration-test.

And the last line will give you the information to which life cycle phase the plugin developers have decided to bind the plugin goal by default.

Now answering your questions:

Given them in that way means executing those two goal within the same life cycle phase (integration-test). The order is given by the order in the pom file.

> Does verify goal (bound to verify phase) will be executed in
>   integration-test phase?

No. Based on the given configuration verify goal is **NOT** bound to verify life cycle phase, cause it's bound to `integration-test` phase.

Comment: thanks for elaborate answer. but given the way in documentation you linked, plugin is invoked twice when I run `mvn verify` (one during integration-test phase and one in verify)

Comment: can you please help with edit to my question. I will accept this answer right away.